Mudblazor Mudtable layout not filling width in mobile layout
If you create a brand new Blazor Wasm App from the template in VS 17.10.5 using Net 8, add in the latest nugget MudBlazor package with the required setup, then replace the home page with:
@page "/"

@using MudBlazor

<MudTable Items="@tableData" T="TableData" Striped="true">
    
    <ColGroup>
        <col style="width: 20%"/>
        <col style="width: 15%" />
        <col style="width: 15%" />
        <col style="width: 15%" />
        <col style="width: 15%" />
        <col style="width: 20%" />
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Column 01</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Column 02</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Column 03</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Column 04</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Column 05</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Column 06</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Column1">@context.Column1</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Column2">@context.Column2</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Column3">@context.Column3</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Column4">@context.Column4</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Column5">@context.Column5</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Column6">@context.Column6</MudTd>
        
    </RowTemplate>
    
</MudTable>



@code{
    private class TableData
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Column2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Column3 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Column4 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Column5 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Column6 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }


    private List<TableData> tableData = new()
    {
       new() { Column1 = "A1", Column2 = "A2", Column3 = "A3", Column4 = "A4", Column5 = "A5", Column6 = "A6" },
       new() { Column1 = "B1", Column2 = "B2", Column3 = "B3", Column4 = "B4", Column5 = "B5", Column6 = "B6" },
       new() { Column1 = "C1", Column2 = "C2", Column3 = "C3", Column4 = "C4", Column5 = "C5", Column6 = "C6" },
       new() { Column1 = "D1", Column2 = "D2", Column3 = "D3", Column4 = "D4", Column5 = "D5", Column6 = "D6" },
       new() { Column1 = "E1", Column2 = "E2", Column3 = "E3", Column4 = "E4", Column5 = "E5", Column6 = "E6" },
       new() { Column1 = "F1", Column2 = "F2", Column3 = "F3", Column4 = "F4", Column5 = "F5", Column6 = "F6" },
       new() { Column1 = "G1", Column2 = "G2", Column3 = "G3", Column4 = "G4", Column5 = "G5", Column6 = "G6" }
        
    };
}

It works as expected in normal layout, but when it breaks into mobile layout, the table is only taking up a small portion of the width of the container, like this:

If I take the exact same code and put it in try.mudblazor.com it works as expected:

There is no css isolation, no additional style sheets - just a fresh new app with Mudblazor added.  Could there be a problem with the css in the template?
I notice that MudBlazor is now recommending that you take out Bootstrap, so I've tried that and it still doesn't work.
Any ideas on why this is happening and is there a fix for it?
Here is a snippet... https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEwSYsYyeiLMGOlZ

I tried your snippet and It doesn't seem to work on try.mudblazor aswell. Seems like a bug with the ColGroup. I recommend raising an issue on their GitHub.

RBee - you are absolutely spot on with that.  If I delete the whole ColGroup it works as expected but the column formatting is not ideal as I was looking for fixed sized columns.  As a work around I have put the  tags within a MudHidden Breakpoint.XS and that appears to have worked.  I'll raise an issue on GitHub to see if they can fix it.  Thanks for your suggestion - it has helped a lot.

This is the default behavior the Table as seen in the documentation.
If you don't want this behavior, you'd need to set the Breakpoint parameter to Breakpoint.None.
<MudTable Items="@tableData" T="TableData" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.None" Striped>

see updated snippet

Thanks for the suggestion but I'm Ok with it breaking out into mobile layout.  It's the layout of the columns in that format that seem incorrect - the table should be as wide as the container, not 1/3rd of it and the rest unused space.  As per RBee's comment above, it looks like a bug and I've determined a workaround for now.

gotcha, misunderstood the problem.

appreciate you taking the time to provide an answer though.
